# Ruby on Rails - Nested Render

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make a multi step sign up form using wicked gem.

But when try a nested render. im getting an error like

> undefined local variable or method `f' for
>
> ## <#:0x007f1d11128718>

new.html.erb

```
    <%= render 'form', name: @name do %>
       <%= render 'form_first_name' %>
    <% end %>

    <%= link_to 'Back', names_path %>
```

_form.html.erb

```
    <%= form_for(name) do |f| %>

         <%= yield %>

         <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit %>
         </div>
    <% end %>
```

_form_first_name.html.erb

```
     <div class="field">
         <%= f.label :first_name %>
         <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
     </div>
```

Comment: You need to pass f as local variable other wise it will not be available. in form first name.

Comment: I tried it but it says nil :(

Comment: Can you please update the code when you are passing the local variable.